# Get object name in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two classes in jquery e.g:

```
function a(){

this.init = function(a){}

}

function b(){

this.init = function(a){}

}
```

Both the classes have **this.init()** method.I have a situation that i have the object of both classes and  i want to call init() method of **class b** how can i know the name of the custom object so that i can easily call the init() method of class b like

```
if (current_object == typeof b)
  current_object.init()
```

Comment: what's this got to do with jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use instanceof,

```
if (current_object instanceof b)
  current_object.init()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `constructor` property of the objects

```
var obj = new b();
console.log(obj.constructor == b);
console.log(obj.constructor == a);
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/9j3HJ/

for `b()` object

```
if (current_object.constructor == b)
    current_object.init();
```